# Invert text colour on scroll, passing over images

Tags: text, scroll, colors, blend

I'm trying to create a text effect like the CHART logo here: https://chartartfair.com/ to invert the colours of the logo as you scroll down the page, passing over different images.

I have tried to adapt this guide: https://css-tricks.com/reverse-text-color-mix-blend-mode/ but it isn't having any effect on the logo.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.